# I'm trying something new with python but isn't working, can anyone help me figure out why the function only prints data[0]?

Tags: python

so I'm trying to change a word string into an integer, and then have the console print the number with the correct commas,

so the string can be "2 million", but I want the console to print 2,000,000 as an integer, including the comma separators,so far this is code I have;

```
def main():
    print("Please enter a number using the word 'thousand' or 'million'.")
    number = input("For example, 1 million or 1 thousand: ")
    data = number.split(" ")
    if data[1] == str.lower('thousand'):
        data[1] = 000
        reply = (int(data[0]) + data[1])
        print(f"{reply:,}")

main()
```

but when I run the code and input "2 thousand", the console just prints the number 2, no zeroes or commas, where am I going wrong?

Comment: seems like your formatting is wrong, because if you input `2 million` in here, it won't do anything

Comment: data[1] is not being printed because it is 0, and it is then added to data[0]

Comment: Yeah that's what I'm trying to fix, thanks for the helpful comment.

Comment: You’re doing number addition. `1 + 0` is `1`. Python doesn’t care about how many zeros you type, `000` is the same numeric value as `0`. You’ll want to work with *strings*, not numbers here.

Comment: Also, you meant `if data[1].lower() == 'thousand':`

Comment: The `+` sign here is mathematical addition as you explicitly apply it on integers, it's not a concatenation that I assume you should do

Comment: Is this for an assignment or a real-life use case? If the latter, use a existing library, like [w2n](https://github.com/akshaynagpal/w2n)

Comment: " when I run the code and input "2 million", the console just prints the number 2" - well, the code you provided wouldn't print anything in this case, so it doesn't match your description.

Comment: Thanks guys, I'll make some changes and see if I screw it up more somehow because I'm a noob

Answer (score 0):

```
def main():
    print("Please enter a number using the word 'thousand' or 'million'.")
    number = input("For example, 1 million or 1 thousand: ")
    data = number.split(" ")
    if data[1] == str.lower('thousand'):
        data[1] = ',000'
        reply = ((data[0]) + data[1])
        # print(f"{reply:,}")
        print(reply)
main()
```

0s are now printed.
You have to add 000 as string.

or

```
def main():
    print("Please enter a number using the word 'thousand' or 'million'.")
    number = input("For example, 1 million or 1 thousand: ")
    data = number.split(" ")
    if data[1] == str.lower('thousand'):
        data[1] = '000'
        reply = int(str(data[0])+data[1])
        numbers = "{:,}".format(reply)
        # print(f"{reply:,}")
        print(numbers)
main()
```

Comment: My assignment is for a class, it says that I must use formatting to get the commas in the number

Comment: https://pythonguides.com/python-format-number-with-commas/#:~:text=In%20Python%2C%20to%20format%20a,thousand%20places%20starting%20from%20left.&text=After%20writing%20the%20above%20code,appear%20as%20a%20%E2%80%9C%205%2C000%2C000%E2%80%9D.

Comment: Refer to this article

Answer (score 0):

you can just replace it in your str :

```
def main():
    print("Please enter a number using the word 'thousand' or 'million'.")
    number = input("For example, 1 million or 1 thousand: ")
    str_number={
        "thousand":"000",
        "million":"000,000"
    }
    print(','.join([str_number[e] if e in str_number else e for e in number.split(' ')]))    

main()
```

Comment: My assignment says that I have to use formatting to get the commas in the number

Comment: check last update

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use integers, you can do:

```
        reply = int(data[0]) * 1000 # or 1000000 if "million"
```

Answer (score 0):

```
def main():
    print("Please enter a number using the word 'thousand' or 'million'.")
    number = input("For example, 1 million or 1 thousand: ")
    data = number.split(" ")
    if data[1] == 'thousand':
        data[1] = ',000'
        reply = ((data[0]) + data[1])
        # print(f"{reply:,}")
        print(reply)
    elif data[1] == str.lower('million'):
        data[1] = ',000,000'
        reply = ((data[0]) + data[1])
        # print(f"{reply:,}")
        print(reply)
main()
```

You can change data[1] to a string with commas

Comment: What's the point of doing `str.lower('thousand')`? The string is already lowercased...

Comment: @Tomerikoo That's from the question.

Comment: @TõnisPiip So? It's nonsense... Why not fix it (or at least remove it)? Or even point the OP to the mistake

Comment: Also why did you post two separate answers??? I don't see any significant changes to the other answer...

Comment: In 2nd answer i added of millions also

Answer (score 0):

I'd use a similar approach to Satyam Shankar, but perhaps with a dictionary to dynamically replace "million" or "thousand" with the appropriate string:

```py
def main():
    replacement = {"thousand":",000",\
                   "million" :",000,000"
                  }
    print("Please enter a number using the word 'thousand' or 'million'.")
    number = input("For example, 1 million or 1 thousand: ")
    data = number.split(" ")
    if data[1] == str.lower('thousand'):
        data[1] = replacement[data[1]]
        reply = ((data[0]) + data[1])
        # print(f"{reply:,}")
        print(reply)
main()
```

This approach is quite extensible; you could add the ability to use "billion", "trillion", etc. by extending the replacement dictionary.

In extending this further, think about what about you might want if the user inputs, for example, "twelve thousand", "1.7 million" or "2 million 543 thousand 819"?